# Logitech G502 script changed how to activate the Lua script

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

PROFILE_ACTIVATED EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents work perfectly before Logitech Driver Update and after that Script is work but it change how to active the script, i changed to mouse 2 to 5 it still work just only one button and how to make it work right now is left click first follow by right click but i want just only left click
how can i fix to use mouse same as before?

the script

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
    end
 if IsKeyLockOn("capslock")then
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(3)then
        repeat
        MoveMouseRelative(0, 1)
        Sleep(10)
        until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: Replace `IsMouseButtonPressed(3)` with `IsMouseButtonPressed(1)` to run the script by only LMB

Comment: How does it `not work` exactly?  Do you see some error message?

Comment: i still need to left click and follow by right click to activate script

Comment: no error message everything work but how to make it work not same as before

Comment: OK, try to insert `Sleep(10)` below the first line `function OnEvent(event, arg)`

Comment: before this happen i use it by right click before left click to activate but now is left click before right click how is so weird i don't know how fix it

Comment: try that already not work and try by put primary click on mouse 4 in Logitech G hub it work same as before maybe problem is from logitech driver i think

Comment: What is the `Logitech Driver Update` you have mentioned?  What exactly was updated? Which version of GHub you have?

Comment: now the version is 2023.7.446315

Comment: How have you got this new version?  The latest available GHub version is [2023.6.430723](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025298133#).  I have 2023.6 installed and "CHECK FOR UPDATE" button does not find anything newer.  Try to deinstall your GHub and install it again starting from [the official page](https://www.logitechg.com/en-us/innovation/g-hub.html).  BTW, what is your OS?

Comment: i actuallly have 2023.7 and i'm on Windows 10, i uninstalled and download older version already think is happen because new driver now i have 2021 version and it work now thank you so much